# sum of all the numbers below 1000 that are multiples of 3 or 5

Tags: c++, sum

[Project Euler problem 1](http://projecteuler.net/index.php?section=problems&id=1) is: Find the sum of all the multiples of 3 or 5 below 1000

Here is my program, using two simple functions to work out the sum of all the multiples of 3 and all the multiples of 5 and then add them up:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;


int threeSum( void );

int fiveSum( void );


int main( int argc, char** argv )
{
    cout << "\n The sum of all the natural numbers below 1000 that are multiples of 3 or 5 = \n" << endl;

    cout << threeSum() + fiveSum() << endl << endl;

    system( "PAUSE" );
}


int threeSum( void )
{
    int sumSoFar = 0;

    for ( int i = 1 ; i < 1000 ; i++ )
    {
        if ( i % 3 == 0 )
                            sumSoFar = sumSoFar + i;
    }

    return sumSoFar;
}


int fiveSum( void )
{
    int sumSoFar = 0;

    for ( int i = 1 ; i < 1000 ; i++ )
    {
        if ( i % 5 == 0 )
                            sumSoFar = sumSoFar + i;
    }

    return sumSoFar;
}
```

which produces `266333` as the answer. Is this correct, or am I doing something wrong, as the website checker says this is the wrong answer!

Comment: Look up the inclusion-exclusion principle, which lets you answer this sort of question without using a loop at all!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As most others pointed out, you're summing the multiples of 15 twice.

Just a hint for another solution:

The sum of multiples of 3 below 1000 is

```
SUMBELOW(3,1000) = 3 + 6 + 9 + ... + 999 = 3*(1+2+3+...+333) = 3*333*(1+333)/2 = 3*((1000-1)/3)*(1+(1000-1)/3)/2
```

(All divisions are integer divisions...)

There are similar formulas for calculating the sums of multiples of 5 and 15. To get the overall result, you have to add the sums for 3 and 5 and subtract the sum for 15...

Comment: You have a problem in your math... remember arithmetic sums are `n * (n+1) / 2`, not `(n+1)/2`, as you have.

Answer (score 7):

Another way of seeing this is:

answer = (sum of multiplies of 3) + (sum of multiplies of 5) - (sum of multiples of 15)

these are simple arithmetic series so you don't even need loops.

Answer (score 2):

You are summing up with all the multiples of 15. This is an easy mathematical problem:

In the case of 15, since it is dividable by both 3 and 5, you are counting it twice in both of the functions.

I suggest that you can use one single loop and `||`. Of course, a single formula would be better, but that's just mathy, I doubt you will like it:)

BTW, Project Euler is more math/computer science than pure programming, so when in doubt, try to think in a mathy way:)

Answer (score 1):

Your solution does not take into account the fact that some numbers (like 15) are divisible by both 5 and 3. You are adding them twice in your sum.

Answer (score 1):

My guess is you're double counting the common multiples of 3 *and* 5.

Answer (score -1):

This is the best answer and the easiest I could do:

```
{
int sum ;

for (int i=1;i<1000;i++){
    if (i%3==0 || i%5==0) sum+=i;
  }
cout<<sum;
}
```

Comment: okay I regret flagging this for deletion. In the moment I did, I was thinking "while this question isn't wrong, I just don't see it as granting insight into _why_ it solves the problem- unlike the other answers". sorry.